# htaccess non www to www and remove subdomain www

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I've got the following rewrite code in my htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

//
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.([^\.]*)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://%1.domain.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

Works perfect for redirecting non-www to www for my domains.

I've got a subdomain, lets call it '`sub.domain.com`' which works find. If I goto `www.sub.domain.com`, it redirecting to '`sub.domain.com/sub/`'
Anyone having a idea why?

Comment: What's broken? As in what's the expected behavior?

Comment: I suppose there is another rewriterule that internally rewrites your subdomain to the right directory. The redirect makes this visible. Match your rule against `^%1/(.*)$` instead and it should work as you expect.

Comment: @Sumurai8 it's not redirecting, www.sub.domain.com -> sub.domain.com

Comment: I guess it works differently than I thought it would. If this happens every time, and you can't move the rewrite rules after the redirect rules, match `^[^/]+/(.*)$` instead. Add a slash between `com` and `$1` too.

Answer (score 0):

None of the rules you have in your question routes requests to a subdomain's folder. The `/sub/` should never be there if it wasn't originally in the request.

That said, all of your redirect rules need to come **before** any routing rules. Routing rules being stuff that internally routes requests to other URI's, for example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^\.]*)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /%1/$1 [L]
```

That rule internall routes to a folder named the same thing as the subdomain. If this rule were to be *before* the redirect, both rules get applied and the redirected URI becomes `/sub/`. You need your routing rules placed **after** your redirect rules, e.g. all rules that have a `http://` or an `R` flag.